# Table & complex exponential (Arbitrary‐Precision) operations efficiency issue

Tags: performance-tuning

Below is the expression I want to optimize, ('I' represent the imaginary unit):

```
ParallelTable[Flatten[Exp[I*n*list]], {n, -10, 10}];
```

as you can see I already used `ParallelTable` but I think the speed could be improved further.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = SetPrecision[RandomReal[10, {64, 64}], 30];

t1 = ((array1 = ParallelTable[Flatten[Exp[I*n*list]], {n, -10, 10}];) // 
    RepeatedTiming)[[1]]

(* 1.8 *)
```

On my Mac, just using `Table` rather than `ParallelTable` is more than four times faster

```
t2 = ((array2 = Table[Flatten[Exp[I*n*list]], {n, -10, 10}];) // 
    RepeatedTiming)[[1]]

(* 0.384 *)

array1 === array2

(* True *)

t1/t2

(* 4.7 *)
```

Comment: Sorry, I still not get it. Why Table here in your mac is even faster? And I don't have mac to do a  test...

Comment: @cj9435042 `Table` is often faster as `ParallelTable`, not only on a mac. Parallelization has always a certain overhead, so you need really big problems with few communication between threads in order to see any improvement in the timings. My guess is that you won't get it faster without machine precision.